# explanation of perl script using lazy evaluation

Tags: perl, lazy-evaluation

I would like to understand what is happening in each step of the execution of the perl script below, I mean, I know what variables, hash, integer array are, but I don't know how they are interacting in this powerset construct using lazy evaluation.
I would also like to know which factors determine which step is the progress of the `sub powerset(&@)` subroutine.
For example, I would like to start printing from the sixth subset, not the first, so which values of which variables should I substitute?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub powerset(&@) {
    my $callback = shift;
    my $bitmask = '';
    my $bytes = @_/8;
    {
       my @indices = grep vec($bitmask, $_, 1), 0..$#_;
       $callback->( @_[@indices] );
       ++vec($bitmask, $_, 8) and last for 0 .. $bytes;
       redo if @indices != @_;
    }
}
 
powerset { print "[@_]\n" } 1..21;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `my $bytes = @_/8;` : Here `@_` is the array input argument so `@_ = 1..21` and when evaluated in scalar context it returns the length of the array. So `$bytes = 21/8 = 2.625`
- `my @indices = grep vec($bitmask, $_, 1), 0..$#_;` Here `$#_` is the last index in `@_` which is 20. So this runs grep on the array `0..20`. For each element in the array, it is checked if the corresponding bit value in `$bitmask` is set, if it is set it is saved in the `@indices` array.
- `$callback->( @_[@indices] );` : This calls the callback function with the array of indices which corresponds to the bits set in `$bitmask`. Since `$bitmask` is initially empty, in the first iteration, `@indices` will be equal to the empty array `[]`.
- `++vec($bitmask, $_, 8) and last for 0 .. $bytes;` : Loops from 0..2 since `$bytes == 2.625` it is rounded down to the nearest integer value. For each bytes index value in `0..2` the corresponding byte in `$bitmask` (treated now as an array of bytes) is incremented. The new byte value is returned from `vec`, if the returned value is nonzero the for loop exits (due to the `and last` part. However, if the value of the byte was 255, `++vec($bitmask, $_, 8)` will return a 0 (the byte value wraps around to zero) and the next iteration of the `for 0..$bytes` `for` loop will execute.
- `redo if @indices != @_;` runs the block (lines 7-12) again if the length of the `@indices` array is different from the length of `@_` (i.e.: 21).

Comment: your explanation is detailed, but I still don't understand how I can get a shortcut if for example I wanted to print the sixth subset. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you use the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68795176/2173773) answer ?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/2yewxjXW) is an example of how you can restart the sequence after a given limit

Comment: thanks for the help, i will analyze your code, in other words i would like to start printing "from the sixth set", so i would need to discard the timing and calculation of previous sets, that's what i meant, i will check your example.

Comment: I sent an email, I did not find chat option on part of the issue of printing from a specific subset, I changed to try to achieve this goal, but would like your review to have your opinion. here example https://pastebin.com/bwPKFDP1.